# Is Devise's :authenticate_user! the same as :signed_in_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is from the [Rails Tutorial Book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/):

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

```
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]


  def signed_in_user
    unless signed_in?
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice: "Please sign in."
    end
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
```

So the code is letting users create and destroy posts only if they are signed in.

I was wondering if doing this with **Devise** `before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy]`. Results in the same thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not the same! You must use

`before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :destroy`

in your case. Watch these videos for better understanding:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise

UPDATE:

Here is a complete list of devise wiki articles: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/_pages

Comment: Nikilov so basically, `authenticate_user!` is replacing `:signed_in_user` from my code about?

Comment: Yes - your code should become: `before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]`